# res.redirect not responding in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

imagine user click on something and a modal dialog appear, he done key in the things and the modal close. What should I do next after I send the data back to the db? I do `res.redirect('store')` but it does nothing, I know what's the problem because I'm already on localhost:2000/store.

I was expecting a refresh because the user just added / updated the data. How will you do it in your case? I'm using node with express 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Ajax to send data from modal to the server? In this case redirect you send from server will not work, it the Ajax request will be redirected only. If you want to refresh the page you need to do this on the client after you receive the response for your request.

Could you provide more details so I can provide a complete answer?

Comment: you mean I should do my refresh after my ajax is done? u make sense.

Comment: I do a res.send('ok'), and then I catch in the client side, work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

In my frontend modal code using Angularjs, I redirect the client only when I successfully get data back from the server using 'window.loction'

Client code (angular):

```
     $http({ method: 'POST',  url: '/login', data:user
           }).then(function successCallback(response) {

              if (response.status===200) {
                  $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                  window.location.href = '/home';    <<< redirect user here

              } else {
                    console.log('unexpected response:', response)
              }

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
              if (response.status === 401) {
                  console.log("scope:",$scope)
                  $scope.loginform.notauthorised = true;

               }
                  console.log('err: ', response);
             });
```

Comment: will this have a 'flash'? as I know angularjs is good at rending template at blazing fast speed.

Comment: window.location will initiate a new page load, so will 'flash'. If thats not wanted, you could do a manual refreshing using some kind of xhr